# SwiftUI .searchable doesn't appear when pushing view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

The `.searchable()` searchbar isn't showing when you push a view, only in a modal. Is this intentional by Apple or am I implementing it incorrectly?

Video and code below:

[image: searchable not in pushed view]

Home View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSearchView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SearchView()
                ) {
                    Text("Push Search View")
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                
                Button {
                    showSearchView = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Modal Search View")
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSearchView) {
            SearchView()
        }
    }
}
```

Search View

```
struct SearchView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Searching for \(searchText)")
                .navigationTitle("Searchable Example")
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "Look for something")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to have one `NavigationStack` in a flow instead of creating a new one each time you push a `View` using `NavigationLink`.
However, it's worth noting that when you use the `.searchable` modifier within the stack, the search bar appears normally:

```
struct SearchView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Searching for \(searchText)")
                .navigationTitle("Searchable Example")
                .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "Look for something")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer was spot on. Doing your change (putting .searchable in the subview) works but you're right about not using NavigationStack repeatedly in same stack, I switched it to NavigationView and it works fine as well. Thanks!